# Using Photoshop Actions on Images uploaded by Users

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications, photoshop

I want to have a user upload a image to my website and have a series of Photoshop actions like adding a layer behind of that image, a layer infront and some dynamic text with effects applied to it like drop shadow and gradient overlay. Is this even possible?

Comment: I've never done this so I can't give specific advice, but Adobe has [documentation on scripting Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) that may be helpful

Comment: Do you mean I can have some sort of Photoshop engine on my web server that my web app can access?

Comment: I've elaborated in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Various [Image Processing and Generation functions provided by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) mainly ImageMagick & GD. If that does not prove to be sufficient,

Consider [Gimp command line](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). you can easily invoke it from php using *exec()* function. GIMP is full featured & can do almost all fancy Photoshop actions you would want. And its free!

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

PHP libraries are available to perform some basic graphics manipulation, as mentioned in the other answer. If these aren't adequate for you, it looks as though you can run and script the normal Photoshop program on your server. Photoshop is not available for Linux, so you'd probably need a Windows server. (This wouldn't be doable on shared hosting, you'd probably need a decent VPS at least.)

I haven't done this before, but according to [Adobe Photoshop Scripting documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) your language choices are JavaScript and VBScript. Someone could write a PHP library to access this, but I don't know of anything like that.